# Open Source - EER Modeling Tool

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, data-modeling, eer-model

What is a good open source or reasonably priced EER modeling tool for MySQL besides MySQL Workbench?  I find the MySQL Workbench interface to be clunky. I would like to be able to manage my production schema beginning all design changes in the EER and propogating those out to my schema for created and altered tables.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try [SQL Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) or [DBschema](http://www.dbschema.com/).
I never used them but got good feedback.